# how to reverse a string in solidity?

Tags: solidity

hello guys this is my code and i want to reverse a string with solidity :

```
function reverseValue(string _base) internal returns(string){
        bytes memory _baseBytes = bytes(_base);

        string memory _tempValue = new string(_baseBytes.length);
        bytes memory _newValue = bytes(_tempValue);

        for(uint i=_baseBytes.length;i<=0;i--){
            _newValue[_baseBytes.length - i] = _baseBytes[i];
        }

        return string(_newValue);
    }
```

but the only result is this code below : 
`0:string : \u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000`

i think i wrote my code right but i cant find the problem ... tnx to help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found this answer and this is the right code :

```
function reverseValue(string _base) internal returns(string){
        bytes memory _baseBytes = bytes(_base);
        assert(_baseBytes.length > 0);

        string memory _tempValue = new string(_baseBytes.length);
        bytes memory _newValue = bytes(_tempValue);


        for(uint i=0;i<_baseBytes.length;i++){
            _newValue[ _baseBytes.length - i - 1] = _baseBytes[i];
        }

        return string(_newValue);
    }
```

now the result for this particular code is :

```
_base : "shahab" -> result : 0 : string : "bahahas"
```

Comment: Strings in solidity are presumed to be encoded with utf-8. Many international characters are longer than one byte in utf-8, so reversing the bytes naively will likely produce a corrupted (or non-decodable) result.

Comment: @carver thank you dear friend i'm just started to learning solidity and this was a great tip ... tnx ... but can you tell me some practices for learning solidity in real world..??