# How to reverse the digits of a uint in solidity?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am trying to write a function to reverse the digits of a uint in a solidity smart contract.

I saw [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48600478) that shows how to reverse a *string* in solidity by looping through the bytes of a passed string from back to front, but since I am only concerned with integers I wondered if there was a way to do so that only used integers, and was able to appropriately handle overflows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching around I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64298936) that gives a solution to this very problem in C. I was able to tweak this to work in Solidity.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Reverse {
    function reverse_recurse(uint i, uint r) internal returns(uint) {
      if (i != 0) {
        uint least_digit = i % 10;
        if (r >= type(uint).max / 10 && (r > type(uint).max / 10 || least_digit > type(uint).max % 10)) {
          return 0; /// Overflow
        }
        r = reverse_recurse(i / 10, r * 10 + least_digit);
      }
      return r;
    }
    
    // Reverses digits in a uint, overflow returns 0
    function reverse_int(uint i) public returns(uint) {
      return reverse_recurse(i, 0);
    }
}
```

```
 decoded input  { "uint256 i": "12345" }
 decoded output { "0": "uint256: 54321" }
```

Unlike the C solution this works only for unsigned ints as that was all I was needing.

Answer (score 1):

Above answer seem to complicated to me so decided to create something on my own

```
function reverseNumber(uint n) public pure returns(uint) {
uint num = n;
uint reversedNum = 0;

while(true) {
    if (reversedNum == 0) {
        reversedNum = num % 10;
    } else {
        reversedNum = (reversedNum * 10) + (num % 10);
    }

    if(num < 10) {
        break;
    }

    num = num / 10;
  }

return reversedNum == n ? 1 : 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the above examples as below. You can use iterative loop or recursion to solve this problem.

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.9;

contract Maths {
    function reverse(uint256 num) public pure returns (uint256 result) {
        while (num != 0) {
            uint256 div = num / 10;
            uint256 rem = num % 10;
            result = result * 10 + rem;
            num = div;
        }
    }

    function reverse_r(uint256 num) public pure returns (uint256 result) {
        return reverse_recu(num, 0);
    }

    function reverse_recu(uint256 num, uint256 acc)
        internal
        pure
        returns (uint256 result)
    {
        return num == 0 ? acc : reverse_recu(num / 10, acc * 10 + (num % 10));
    }
}
```